# How to limit buffering when concurrently processing streams with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I have an interleaved stream which I [split into separate sequential streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135968/how-to-read-interleaved-file-concurrently-using-reactive-extensions).

**Producer**

```
int streamCount = 3;

new MyIEnumerable<ElementType>()
.ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
.Select((x,i) => new { Key = (i % streamCount), Value = x })
.Subscribe(x => outputs[x.Key].OnNext(x.Value));
```

Where `outputs[]` are Subjects which process the streams are defined below. The `.ObserveOn()` is used to process the streams concurrently (multi-threaded).

**Consumers**

```
var outputs = Enumerable.Repeat(0, streamCount).Select(_ => new Subject<char>()).ToArray();                                                                                                     

outputs[0].ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("stream 0: {0}", x));
outputs[1].ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("stream 1: {0}", x));
outputs[2].ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("stream 2: {0}", x));
```

The problem with this code is that it will read the entire enumerable as fast as possible, even if the output streams cannot catch up. In my case the enumerable is a file stream so this might cause using a lot of memory. Therefore, I would like the reading to block if the buffer(s) reach some threshold.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by using a semaphore on the producer and consumers like shown below. However, I am not sure that this is considered a good solution (in terms of Rx contracts, programming style, etc).

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MAX_BUFFERED_ELEMENTS);

// add to producer (before subscribe)
.Do(_ => semaphore.Wait());

// add to consumer (before subscribe)
.Do(_ => semaphore.Release()))
```

It might be a good idea to pass a `CancelationToken` to the call to `Wait()` and make sure it is cancelled when the stream stops abnormally?

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is very reasonable. The biggest problem (having some background to the previous question) is that the 'insides' of your solution are currently exposed everywhere. Just make sure that when you code this properly you clean up the following:

- Wrap everything into a class that exposes a single method: `IDisposable Subscribe(<index>, Action)` or alternatively `IObservable<element> ToObservable(<index>))`. Either the returned subscription or the returned observable will have all the 'work' already done to them, namely the added `Do` actions and so forth. The fact that there's a dictionary or list under it all should be completely irrelevant to the user, otherwise any change to your code here will require changes all over the place.
- A `CancelationToken` is a great idea, make sure to cancel it on either `OnCompleted` or `OnError`, which you can do using overloads to `Do`.